# Flask. Python. Show rendered templates

Tags: python, signals, flask

I'm pretty new to `Flask` and `python`, don't judge much :)
I'm trying to modify `response`, so my application would show rendered templates list in footer. My `get_rendered_templates` function is:

```
def get_rendered_templates(context):
  from contextlib import contextmanager

  @contextmanager
  def rendered_templates(context):
    templates = []
    def add(sender, template, context):
      assert False
      templates.append((template, context))
    template_rendered.connect(add, context)
    try:
      yield templates
    finally:
      template_rendered.disconnect(add, context)

  with rendered_templates(context) as templates:
    return templates
```

this is what I've found in documentation to `Flask` and slightly modified.

Anyway, this function returns `None`, `add` function is never executed (or the application would terminate because of `assert False`).

my `after_request`:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
  rendered_templates = get_rendered_templates(app)
  templates_list = "<br />".join(["%s" % template for (template, context) in rendered_templates ])
  response.data = "%(current)s <br /> temsplates: %(templates)s" % {'current': response.data, 'templates' : templates_list }
  return response
```

What I'm doing wrong? 
What is the right way to do what I'm doing?